# How does set and get commands work in python

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, scripting, set

For a python dictionary something like this,

```
data={
       'name':'george',
       'isRetired': True,
       'organisation': ['ABC','XYZ','MNO'],
        
     }
```

How does set and get works here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
while True:
    cmd = input('> ').split()
    if cmd[0] == 'get':
        key = ' '.join(cmd[1:])
        path = key.split('.')
        now = data
        for k in path:
            if k in now:
                now = now[k]
            else:
                print('Error: invalid key')
        print(now)
    elif cmd[0] == 'set':
        key, value = ' '.join(cmd[1:]).split('=')
        path = key.split('.')
        now = data
        for k in path[:-1]:
            if k in now:
                now = now[k]
            else:
                print('Error: invalid key')
        now[path[-1]] = value
    elif cmd[0] == 'quit':  # for debugging purposes
        break
    else:
        print('Error: invalid command')

print(data)
```

This is a pretty long program. It breaks the command down.
If the command is `get`, then break the parameter down by dots and gets the item, one level by one level.
If the command is `set`, then break the parameters into a `key` and a `value`, break the key down by dots and finds the key, and sets the value.
The `quit` command is made for debug purposes.

Debug:

```
> get ABC.positions.lead
3
> get ABC.yearsofService
10
> get name
george
> set ABC.positions.manager=5
> quit
{'name': 'george', 'isRetired': True, 'organisation': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'MNO'], 'ABC': {'currentlyEmployed': False, 'yearsofService': '10', 'positions': {'executive': '2', 'manager': '5', 'lead': '3', 'ceo': None}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was stuck at this. However, I get the following error,                              > get ABC.positions.lead
> File "<stdin>", line 1
    get ABC.positions.lead
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I am using Python 3.8.5 and it works just fine.